# Array of C structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

If I create a struct in C and want to add them to an array that is not set to a fixed size, how is the array created?

Can one create a tempStruct which is used on every iteration while getting user input and store this in an array, always using the same tempStruct struct in the loop?

How is an array created if the size is unknown as it depends on user input, and how are structs added to this array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a tempStruct during input which you add later to the array.

If the size of the array is unknown, then you are in trouble. You must keep track of the array's size somewhere. Just have an integer variable that you change every time you change your array to keep track of your array's size.

If the size of the struct is not known at compile time it is even more complicated. You either just store Pointers in the array which point to your actual struct elements in memory, or you have to keep track of the sizes of every struct in the array. In the later case you would have to do addressing in the array completely manually calculating a lot. While this is very memory efficient, it is also error prone and extremely hard to debug.

OK. sample to create an array that hold your struct using pointers:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  /* code */
}

main()
{
  counter = 0;
  struct MyStruct** array = malloc(counter);
  // Create new Element
  struct MyStruct myElement;
  myElement.someData = someValue;

  // Add element to array:
  array = realloc(array, sizeof(struct MyStruct*) * (counter + 1);
  array[counter] = &myElement;
  counter++;

  // Create yet another new Element
  struct MyStruct myElement;
  myElement.someData = someOtherValue;
  array = realloc(array, sizeof(struct MyStruct*) * (counter + 1);
  array[counter] = &myElement;
  counter++;

  // Now remove the last element
  free(array[counter -1]); // may have something more complicated than that, depending on your struct
  array = realloc(array, sizeof(struct MyStruct*) * (counter - 1);
  counter--;
}
```

this code is not tested!

Comment: so I could create a pointer e.g. struct *tempStruct and just add this so the array using the counter?

Comment: @user604550: Not sure about "so the array using the counter"? Could you clarify?

Comment: @yankee: typo "to the array using the counter?"

Comment: @user604550: Yes, that's it. Just to make sure that we are thinking about the same thing: int counter = 0; YourStruct* array = malloc(...enough space...); array[counter++] = newElement; You might have to use realloc() every time you add an element to increase/shrink the size of your array

Comment: @yankee: thanks. will[counter++] inside the array call increment counter? Or should I array[counter] = tempElement; counter++; ? Also ,how is the size malloced? all the elements in the struct plus the struct size? How much space is needed for a struct itself? Thanks

Comment: @user604550: Both examples with counter should do the same thing. You will need to tell malloc how many bytes you need. Befware of the difference between malloc (new memory) and realloc (change size of the array). The size will be sizeof(struct YourStruct)*(counter+1). This only works if the size of your struct is known at compile time. You'll get a compiler error otherwise. In this case you may want the array to only contain pointers as mentioned above.

Comment: @yankee: Yes, I would like to use pointers, so how would the array be malloced and realloced then? Using pointer size? Also, is the memory allocated automatically when pointers are used? thanks

Comment: @user604550: The memory for the pointer (which is saved on the stack) is allocated automatically. The memory used for the data where the pointer is pointing to is NOT allocated automatically. Yes, use sizeof(struct yourStruct*) in your code (the * was added). (actually you could also write sizeof(int*) or any other datatype, but although it might be tempting, don't to increase readability of your code. Read the manual. Here it comes with example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/

Comment: Im really confused now. There are two ways of doing this we are discussing. One using pointers and the other mallocing? sorry, I got confused. What are the steps to create an array of structs, then create a struct and then add a struct to the array? What if the struct holds a dynamic sized variable(another array of strings) thanks.

Comment: @user604550: I edited my answer and included an example. Get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

When the size is unknown at compile time, you'll need to allocate the memory on the heap, rather than in the data segment (where global variables are stored) or on the stack (where function parameters and local variables are stored).  In C, you can do this by calling functions like malloc.

```
MyStructType *myArray = (MyStructType *)malloc(numElements * sizeof(MyStructType)
... do something ...
free(myArray)
```

If you're actully using C++, it's generally better to use new[] and delete[], e.g.

```
MyStructType *myArray = new MyStructType[numElements]
... do something ...
delete [] myArray
```

Note that new[] must be paired with delete[].  If you're allocating a single instance, use new and delete (without "[]").  delete[] and delete are not equivalent.

Also, if you're using C++, it's generally easier and safer to use an STL vector.

Comment: What is numElements? What if I have a struct consisting of different data types.

Comment: numElements is the number of elements you wish to put in the array.

Answer (score 0):

the C array must be with fixed size this is what we have learned years ago
but memory allocation functions may help you to find a solution

in c++ you can use the operator new

```
int num=0;
cout<<"please enter the number"<<endl;
cin>>num;
int *x=new int[num];
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
   cout<<"enter element "<<(i+1)<<endl;
   cin>>x[i];
}
//do your work
```

and as

> Mr Fooz

mentioned delete[] is used to free the memory allocated by new[]
and this is a general example

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the older C89 standard compiler, you cannot use variable length arrays. If you use C99 then you can create variable length array. For clarification: variable-lenght doesnt mean that the array lenght can change during execution. It just means that you can set it during execution instead of fixing a value during compile time.

For eg:

```
CreateArray(const int numberOfElements)
{
       struct MyStruct arrayOfStructs[numberOfElements];
}
```

This is valid in C99 but not in C89. Check your compiler documentaion.